# In Hadoop HA what happens if a node is down. Suppose if a passive node is down for long time will the cluster run?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2

I know that in Hadoop HA there are two Name nodes i.e Active and passive nodes, if active node goes down passive node acts as namenode and the cluster will run.

Suppose in this two nodes if one node is down for long time assume a week will the cluster run ?

please clarify

Answer (score 0):

When active namenode goes down failover kicks in yo ensure that the active is actually down. Once confirmed the passive namenode comes into action within a few minutes. And fencing process ensures that the previous active namenode is not able to cater to read or write request any longer. Source: Hadoop definative guide. Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: Uday, Thanks for the reply. my question is we will have two namenodes in Hadoop HA. In that if a namenode (Passive one) is down for long time(Assume 1 week) will it affects cluster, i mean will the cluster run normally or any issues ?

Comment: If active is working fine then the cluster should work normally. And I guess the passive namenode cannot remain down for that long as hadoop will start it up from cold using edit log, QJM etc.. So ideally even the passive namenode should not remain down for that long unless serious hardware issues.

Comment: Thankyou uday. From the above answer i understood that there should not be any problem in hadoop HA even if a passive node goes down with hardware failure for a week. i beeive the cluster works fine without issues.